# To generate fixed length random id with variable length random id as input

Tags: java, random, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I am creating a method which would take UUID (as String) as input and generate a 40 Bytes (fixed) output (by adding some more information into it). The length of UUID string is itself 36 characters long (32 characters + 4 hyphens).

I need to make it fit in some thing around 16 characters. Since we are getting this uuid as input, this is our identifier and we do not want to lose it (we might need to regenerate the uuid back with this 16 characters long representation).

Second thing is, we are not sure that we would always receive UUID as input, in future this could be 50 characters long random sequence, so need to generate fixed 16 characters long random sequence for this (also reversible).

Is there any good way to generate fixed length bytes for variable length random input? Need to be sure about uniqueness and also we want that variable length random input back with fixed length bytes.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a database table to map the small key to big key. So that you can lookup later. This is the 100% support for your requirement

The other way is,

Assuming the 36 character UUID only contains 0123456789ABCDEF characters + 4 hypen NOT in random locations,

i.e. abcdef14-15293abd-92835a5e-2524fa32

we can simply represent each character using 4bits. 0 -> 0000 , 1 -> 0001, A -> 1010, B -> 1011 etc...

if we take two 4bit numbers together as one 8bit character, We will get 16 characters.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Buffer{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String input = "abcdef14-15293abd-92835a5e-2524fa32";
        String[] hexNums = input.split("-");
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);

        for(int i =0 ; i < 4; i++){
            long num = Long.parseLong(hexNums[i], 16);
            buffer.putInt((int)(num + Integer.MIN_VALUE));
        }
        byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
        String v = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```